# PHP - TurboSMTP API send email with attachment

Tags: php, email, methods, attachment, email-attachments

I was wondering if it is possible to send amail with (.pdf) attacchment with the TurboSMTP API ( http://serversmtp.com/it/servizio-smtp-api ).
I've noticed that in those API there is no method to add an attachment, maybe I've searched wrong.

***EDIT:***
as mark suggested me, I've contacted the provider, and they said that the service does not allow actually to send email with attachment, and in less than a month they're gonna implement that.

Please, someone mark as closed this topic.

Thanks for help btw.

Comment: You really should contact the provider instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is currently a way to attach file, but you have to build a whole MIME body and pass it using the `mime_raw` post parameter, that overrides content and `html_content`.

To build a valid MIME body you could inspect what `PHPMailer` does when you attach a file, the body is built when you call its `preSend()` method.

Unluckily, I've recently discovered that a MIME body over 150,000 bytes does not get sent. I've opened a ticket with the provider.

Answer (score 0):

I got email from TurboSMTP support that it just added support send mail with attachments
https://www.serversmtp.com/turbo-api/#send-email-2